# How to stop wasting time updating dependencies with composer?

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I am building a small app with some dependencies and my back-end is in PHP with composer and I use many dependencies.

I used to keep the project up-to-date but sometimes, composer update is just to long!

Anyone have some good tips to help me updating my dependencies? any automated service that can run them for me without breaking my code?

Comment: a small app with a ton of libraries, you sure that's effective? Also, why not place whatever you don't need to require-dev, sure you've got a lot you can save

Comment: To answer your question, I'm not sure there isn't any way of doing what you require unless you set only a couple to be updated. I'll upvote this in case someone enlights me aswell

Comment: you may create a cron and run the composer update command as a shell script..however I have never tried this and not sure if this will work

Comment: How long is "toooooooooooo long"? How often are you doing it? What is the detemining factor as to why you choose to do the update? Can you pls rephrase your question so it actually *asks* a well-defined question: what the problem is, in real world terms; what outcome you'd like instead; what's stopping you from achieving that? ATM it sounds like yer letting off steam rather than asking a question you expect someone to actually be able to answer objectively.

Comment: Just wondering, could you share your `composer.json`? There might be spots to improve there.

Comment: Do you use a lot of private repos or forks?

Comment: @AdamCameron I used to do it once every two weeks, now I do it once every two months because it takes me like 30 to 40 minutes after that, I have to run my tests, check what can be fixed

Comment: @karnokrat yep, lovely, but like I suggested "Can you pls rephrase your question so it actually asks a well-defined question: ... [etc]". Which part of it takes 30-40min? What is compelling you to do a composer update at all in the first place? *Ask a lucid question*.

Answer (score 4):

I built [Dependabot](https://dependabot.com) to do exactly this. Every morning it will check with packagist whether there are any new versions, and if there are it will create a pull request to update you to the latest and greatest.

The core of the app is open source [here](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core) and it's relatively popular with Ruby and JavaScript programmers. The PHP beta is fully functional, and I'm looking for more people to give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

I use [prestissimo](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo) for a much faster composer update/install process.
It's a composer plugin aka `composer global require hirak/prestissimo`
and you are done.

It downloads all ur packages simultaneously and installs them!

This will make composer insanely fast.

Benchmark on a Laravel install without prestissimo 288s => 
with prestissimo 26s!!!

For automating ur Process you could set up a [cronjob](http://awc.com.my/uploadnew/5ffbd639c5e6eccea359cb1453a02bed_Setting%20Up%20Cron%20Job%20Using%20crontab.pdf) and let it run a bash script with something like this inside:

Filename in example = composer_update.sh. Content:

```
#!/bin/bash

composer update --no-progress --profile --prefer-stable
```

For not breaking ur code I recommend setting a [minimum stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md) in ur composer.json

The cronjob for updating once a month could look like this

`*/0 0 1 * * /PROJECT_ROOT/composer_update.sh >> update.log`

This [article](https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html) might further help you with cron.

Hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I heard a currently work in progress project wanted to solve this issue.

They link to your github account (you must have one in order for this to work) they want to keep your libraries up-to-date if you're using composer, npm or gem I think.

The thing is, they create a pull-request showing you what will be updated and show you the changelog if there is one for the update.

Take a look at [upgator.io](https://upgator.io)